# Populating column in SQL with multiplication based on existing column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a new column in my SQL table that contains a simple multiplication based on an existing column.
Example of the existing table:

| Product | PricingUSD |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 20 |
| Product B | 40 |

What I want to do:

| Product | PricingUSD | PricingEUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 20 | 20.48 |
| Product B | 40 | 40.96 |

I created the new column with:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD 'PricingEUR' NUMERIC(10);
```

But now I'm not sure how to populate the new column (it is populated with NULL). It needs to take the number from "PricingUSD" and multiply it by 1.08.

I believe it would be related to INSERT TO, so I tried

```
INSERT INTO table (PricingEUR)
VALUES (PricingUSD*1.08);
```

Also tried many variations based on tutorials but none worked. Thoughts?

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?  Also you need `UPDATE`

Comment: What's expected to happen tomorrow if the exchange rate will be 1.09?

Comment: @jarlh nothing really, this is not a scenario I'll cover. I'm doing this as an exercise to learn so exchange variations won't be considered for now...

Comment: @drum MSSQL and MSSQL Server Management - local database.

Comment: `INSERT` is used to _insert_ new rows into the table. Instead use `UPDATE` to _update_ existing rows.

Comment: @jarlh okay so, it would be  UPDATE table (PricingEUR) VALUES (PricingUSD*1.08);? Still doesn't work, column doesn't get data populated

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update/

Comment: If you don't have auto-commit on, then you need to manually `COMMIT`.